# Google Adsense and Private Networks

Tags: google, google-adsense

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out if I can use Google Adsense on a private network. The network is accessible only by registered users, which made me think if it would work or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a verified adsense account before displaying ads on login-protected pages.

To allow crawlers access your pages correctly, follow [these instructions](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=161351) .

In addition, you **must** ensure that other users of the private network are using different public IP addresses with yours because Goolge may think you are trying to cheat then disable your account.

Comment: In my opinion, it is a bad idea to use AdSense on private networks. You may not get much revenue but a significant risk of being banned from AdSense since Google can't watch your private pages normally and think it's not worth to keep you in their network. Remember that Google keeps the right to disable your account for any reason.